# How to print an entire istream to standard out and string

Tags: c++, stream

How do you print an istream variable to standard out. 
[EDIT] I am trying to debug a scenario wherein I need to ouput an istream to a log file

Comment: Please clarify what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to print out the entire string

Answer (score 28):

You ouput the istream's streambuf.

For example, to output an ifstream to cout:

```
std::ifstream f("whatever");
std::cout << f.rdbuf();
```

Answer (score 12):

*Edit:* I'm assuming that you want to copy the entire contents of the stream, and not just a single value. If you only want to read a single word, check 1800's answer instead.

---

The obvious solution is a while-loop copying a word at a time, but you can do it simpler, as a nice oneliner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

...

std::istream i;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(i), std::istream_iterator<char>(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
```

The stream_iterators use operator << and >> internally, meaning they'll ignore whitespace. If you want an exact copy, you can use std::istreambuf_iterator and std::ostreambuf_iterator instead. They work on the underlying (unformatted) stream buffers so they won't skip whitespace or convert newlines or anything.

You may also use:

```
 i >> std::noskipws;
```

to prevent whitespace from disappearing. Note however, that if your stream is a binary file, some other characters may be clobbered by the `>>` and `<<` operators.

Answer (score 7):

This will print the whole stream, 1 character at a time:

```
char c;
c = my_istream.get();
while (my_istream)
{
    std::cout << c;
    c = my_istream.get();
}
```

This will print the whole thing, but discard whitespace:

```
std::string output;
while(my_istream >> output)
    std::cout << output;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read from it, and then output what you read:

```
istream stm;
string str;
stm >> str;
cout << str;
```

Comment: that only reads one word (whitespace delimited). I think he wants to copy everything from the stream.

Comment: I think if he wanted that, he would have said it

Comment: Who knows what he wants, the question is poor.

Answer (score 0):

## std::ifsream overloading and std::ostringstream

## c++11 or upper

---

Pay attention to `&&` in **std::ifstream** that allow you to direct using

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::basic_ostringstream&& iss){
    return os<<iss.str();
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::ifstream&& ifs){
    return std::cout<<ifs.rdbuf();
}


int main()
{
    std::cout<<std::ostringstream("Test ostringstream overloading")<<std::endl;
    std::ofstream("fstream.txt")<<"Test fstream overloading"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::ifstream("fstream.txt")<<std::endl; // overloading okay
}
```

output:

> ```
> Test ostringstream overloading
> Test fstream overloading
>
>
> Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.012 s
> Press ENTER to continue.
> ```

Comment: [basic_ostringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) is a template dependent function. The first function should be converted to be"template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::basic_ostringstream<T>&& iss){
    return os<<iss.str();
}"