# Reading from file line by line

Tags: c++, file

I need to read from file line by line and print it on the screen:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    ofstream out("note.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        out << i << " " << (i<<1) << "\n";
    out.close();


    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("note.txt");

    string line;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {   
        getline(fin, line);
        cout << line << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is this approach correct? Cant I do it without a string variable (without string **line** in code)?

Comment: _"Cant I do it without a string variable (without string line in code)?"_ Could you explain further why you actually want to do so?

Comment: _is this approach correct?_ kind of questions are better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But, about your second question: where do you intend to read the variable to, if not into a variable?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius direct to screen.

Comment: Here are some versions to print an ifstream directly to cout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675953/how-to-print-an-entire-istream-to-standard-out-and-string

Comment: @Hayt: these answers don't provide a line by line solution (assuming that you may want to prepend line numbers).

Comment: Yeah it's not flexible in any way and seems more like a "homework" task. But from what is shown in the OP they do exactly what is tying to be done: Stream in input stream to an output stream. Without more context there are no general "good" solutions.

Comment: `std::getline()` works with a reference to a string parameter to fill in the line. That makes it rather difficult to leave out the variable.  You are probably looking for a version that returns a string.  Even though that might seem handy in your case (`std::cout << std::getline(fin)`), most of the time you want checks whether the reading succeeded and a string-variable to process the input.

Comment: @stefaanv I tried cout << getline() also, it printed random alphanumeric string on screen.

Comment: @sanjoe my answer is not what you are looking for? Would you mind to tell us what exactly do you need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read file line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line)

Comment: @samjoe: `std::getline()` returns std::istream which can be queried to see whether reading succeeded. standard use `while (std::getline(fin, line)) { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a for loop you can use a while loop:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string line;
    ifstream out("note.txt");
    while(getline(out, line)) {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    out.close();
}
```

If you are forced not to use strings then you can try a char buffer `char buf[1024]`. It must be pointed out that this approach is dangerous and error prone. If a line has more than `1024` characters then a `buffer overflow` will occur. Buffer overflow is the cause of many `vulnerabilities` and `crashes`. That being said, if you really have to use this method I would suggest you to be very careful by making the appropriate checks.

Comment: close the file after use

Comment: a fixed size buffer is a really bad idea Kostas.

Comment: @RichardHodges it is, but in the question he asks for a different approach without a `std::string`. I suspect that he meant a char buffer. That's why I included it in my answer. Thanks for pointing out though

Comment: OK, but if this post is to be educational I feel that the example using a fixed-size buffer ought to be fleshed out, complete with overflow protection. It will then be self-explanatory why we don't use fixed-size buffers unless an ancient API demands it.

Comment: @RichardHodges is it better now ?

Comment: :) certainly better. It's interesting that you didn't write the code to do it safely without a std::string. I don't blame you. It's difficult.

Comment: @RichardHodges not really, but reading a file using a buffer is more of c than c++. I have mentioned that a certain feature exist, from there, he can google the details. You can't baby spoon everybody :)

Answer (score 3):

Copying a file verbatim is a simple as streaming out its stream buffer:

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open("note.txt");

std::cout << fin.rdbuf();
```